# Position block text next to element with 'position:relative' and children with 'position:absolute;'

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I would like to have some text next to an element that has a position of relative and children with positions of absolute.
Following [Tania Rascia's tutorial](https://www.taniarascia.com/crossfade-between-two-images-with-css-animations/) I have created 2 crossfading images, it uses `position:absolute` to put the images on top of each other, so that they can fading into each other. However, because `position:absolute` takes the iamges out of the 'flow' or the page, this means that the text from the page is behind the crossfading images.

I have tried applying `display:inline-block` to the parent of the images and the images themselves, but this hasn't changed anything. I am still new to CSS any tips would be helpful.

```css
.cross-fade {
  position: relative;
}

.cross-fade img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 510px;
  height: 350px;
}

.top {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.crossfade-images img.top {
  animation-name: crossfade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-text-container">
  <section class="cross-fade">
    <img class="bottom" alt="" src="//unsplash.it/300/300">
    <img class="top" alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
  </section>

  /*This is the text that is being hidden by the images*/

  <div>
    <div>
      <pre><div id="pre-div">Text goes in here. Hello! Welcome to my website.</div></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by moving the `width` and `height` properties off the child images, to the parent container that held the slideshow.

This should be aesthetically the same but help the document understand how large the slideshow is.

```css
.cross-fade {
  position: relative;
  width: 510px;
  height: 350px;
}

.cross-fade img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.crossfade-images img.top {
  animation-name: crossfade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-text-container">
  <section class="cross-fade">
    <img class="bottom" alt="" src="//unsplash.it/300/300">
    <img class="top" alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
  </section>

  /*This is the text that is being hidden by the images*/

  <div>
    <div>
      <pre><div id="pre-div">Text goes in here. Hello! Welcome to my website.</div></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I am struggling to get a block text to be next to the image on desktop and for the text to be under the image on mobile. Any tips?

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh I recommend researching responsive design (CSS media queries and the viewport meta tag).